# How can I activate a list item with selenium and phantomjs?

Tags: python, selenium, web, phantomjs

```
 from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
dcap = dict(DesiredCapabilities.PHANTOMJS)
dcap["phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent"] = (
     "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/53 "
     "(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/29.0.1547.57 Safari/537.36")
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(desired_capabilities = dcap,service_args=['--ignore-ssl-errors=true', '--load-images=false'])
driver.get("http://www.pcna.com/leeds/pages/product.aspx?cat=PCNA&pid=7950-01_REG")
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
try:
    driver.find_elements_by_xpath("""/html/body/form/div[3]/div[5]/div/div/div/div[4]/div/div/div[5]/div/ul/li[1]""").context_click()
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    div_s = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/body/form/div[3]/div[5]/div/div/div/div[4]/div/div/div[5]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/h3")
    # div_s = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("""//*[@id="mountRoot"]/div/div/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr""")
    size_data = ''
    for s in div_s:
        print (str(s.get_attribute("textContent")))
except NoSuchElementException:
    print ("NoSuchElementException")
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-6-ec79bd8d183a>", line 12, in <module>
    driver.find_elements_by_xpath("""/html/body/form/div[3]/div[5]/div/div/div/div[4]/div/div/div[5]/div/ul/li[1]""").context_click()
```

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'context_click'

I am trying to get the ajax data from a list item. I don't know any other way to activate the li so the data can be scrapped?

Comment: A list has zero or more elements.  Do you want to do `ele.context_click()` for each element `ele`? For only the first element?

Comment: Actually just the second element.. either way, I have tried using multiple events on the element and no of them seem to work because it says its a list object... I just need an event to activate the second element which is a tab so the ajax data can be activated and scrapped

Comment: try `driver.find_elements_by_xpath("""/html/body/form/div[3]/div[5]/div/div/div/div[4]/div/div/div[5]/div/ul/li[1]""")[1].context_click()` note the `[1]` which accesses the second element of the list

Comment: driver.find_elements_by_xpath("""/html/body/form/div[3]/div[5]/div/div/div/div[4]/div/div/div[5]/div/ul/li[2]""")[0].click()

Comment: above is what worked, I didnt realize I had to add the [0] so it would select the exact element... Thanks for the help!!